# Delete the previous and next HTML element by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to delete the previous and next HTML element after using the mouse highlighting the selected text by javascript, but I only know how to get the selected/highlighted text, can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
function text() {
    if (window.getSelection)
        return window.getSelection();
    if (document.getSelection)
        return document.getSelection();
    if (document.selection)
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    return "";
}

function delete_Tag () {

    var txt =  text();
        // txt already have the selected text   
        // I don't know how to do in here !!!   
        // I use the use the find the parentNode, but don't know how to delete the </span>
}

<input type='button' value='Delete Tag' onclick='delete_Tag ()' />

<p id='text'>
<span class="B">I am </span>
<span class="B">working in </span>
<span class="C">ABC company.</span>
</p>
```

e.g. I use the mouse to highlight the 'working in ' ***OR*** 'orkin' ***(the selected must be within the )*** and click the button, it will show

Expected Result:

```
<p id='text'>
<span class="B">I am </span>
working in 
<span class="C">ABC company.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: If I select "working in ABC" what behabiour is expected?

Comment: @Molecule, no expected behavior, but it should be not change for the code.

Comment: So result must be the same as for  'working in' or nothing must be changed?

Comment: it should be nothing to change if the 'working in ABC' is selected

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like the following:

```
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("B").item(0);
        var parent = span.parentNode;
        var sibling = span.nextSibling;
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(span.innerHTML);

        parent.removeChild(span);
        parent.insertBefore(textNode, sibling);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't know how to apply the target into my case, would you explain more?

Comment: I've updated my answer, use the delete_tag function instead of yours. Also pass the e param manually. Please take a look at the updated post. Does it work?

Comment: okay, it is my mistake, I did not see that the click event is for the input, so e.target is a wrong target. I will update my example in a minutes.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what if all the class is ="B", is it possible to get the nearest html element instead of the B[0]? Thank you

Comment: I am ready, here is the correct code use it in the delete_tag function! :)

Comment: @Cenady Sergeev, thanks for you answer again :), but I also need to handle another cases, the order may be different (I update the example), is it possible to use another way to do that instead of using the index, item(0)? Thank you.

Comment: thanks for you answer again :), but I also need to handle another cases, the order may be different (I update the example), is it possible to use another way to do that instead of using the index, item(0)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery `hide` method.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I want the basic javascript, not the jQuery and other library.

Comment: The hard part of this question is identifying the elements to be deleted, so this doesn't help much. `hide` doesn't *delete* the elements anyway, that would be `remove`.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes it should be `remove`. I was Googling to see if Jquery have any event to get highlighted text. But John dont want Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your having trouble deleting the elements, it may be more efficient to hide the selected elements rather than using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need do some extra stuff. You need catch document.body.onmousedown and document.body.onmouseup. If targets of this events are the same node then you have to save this node for further use.

I have created [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/EFQL2/11/) for you

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I found that your example does not work on the site, would you mind to take a look on that?

Comment: @John, it works fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/EFQL2/11/). I won't be able to help if I couldn't see yours site code.

Comment: I open the working example, and then I use the mouse to highlight 'working in ', then click the button, did I do anything wrong?

Comment: @John. Damn, I didn't check for 'working in '. But it works for 'working in', 'orking' and so on.

Comment: @John, I've [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/EFQL2/12/) my script. But it has some bugs. Anyway, I'm only showing you idea. You can improve it to the ideal state. Hope it'll help.